# How to traverse & query faster TitanGraph with Cassandra as a backend?

Tags: indexing, apache-spark, cassandra, graph-databases, titan

I have millions of nodes stored in Titan 1.0.0 with **Cassandra** 2.2.4. I want to retrieve graph from Cassandra and query or traverse it in fast way.

If I build index in a code,

```
mgmt.buildIndex("nameSearchIndex", Vertex.class).addKey(namep, Mapping.TEXT.asParameter()).buildMixedIndex("search");
mgmt.buildIndex("addressSearchIndex", Vertex.class).addKey(addressp, Mapping.TEXT.asParameter()).buildMixedIndex("search");
```

Still the querying seems to be slower.

When I use

```
g.traversal().V().count()
```

it still gives **warning -  please use indexes**, when I have already build indexes in code. Is there any specific configuration to forcefully activate indexes? How to query graph with using indexes?

```
g.traversal().V().has("Name","Jason")
```

Does this query uses indexes? if not then how do I make use of indexes to query faster?

Can Spark be used for fast traversal? How to use **SparkComputerGraph** for the same? I am not able to find the configurations for **CassnadraInputFormat** with Spark.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

There are lots of questions bundled up in this question.

The indexes you're making are *mixed* indexes, which are implemented by an external indexing system, such as Solr or ElasticSearch. These would help if you are looking for a vertex with a certain name, such as your `.has("Name", "Jason)` example.

To find out if an index is being used, I suggest looking into the `profile()` step in Gremlin. You can [read about it here](http://tinkerpop.apache.org/docs/3.0.0-incubating/#profile-step).

Spark is meant to be used for traversals that need to potentially load a graph that is bigger than one machine can hold. What use case is `.V().count()` important for?

Comment: Thanks for reply. I have created a large no of vertices and now I want to perform some analytics on the  top of that using queries and traversal. I need it to be faster. Right now, even I build index in code as specified, it does not make use of index, when i use has("Name","Jason"), it warns  to use indexes. Is there any config  where I have to explicitly specify?

Comment: The indexes Titan provides, how do we make use of them?

Comment: Jason's answer has the details for the particular index you're looking for.

Answer (score 1):

This answer was cross-posted on the Titan [mailing list](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/aureliusgraphs/UcPu_j6XdFc/yenKXu4WDAAJ).

Indexing is useful for doing fast traversals, but ultimately "fast queries" depends on many factors, including your graph model/volume/shape and the types of questions you are trying to answer.

Read Chapter 8 "[Indexing for better Performance](http://s3.thinkaurelius.com/docs/titan/1.0.0/indexes.html)" in the Titan docs, and digest the differences between the different types: Composite, Mixed, and Vertex-centric.

Based on the example query you posted, and as Daniel noted, it looks to me like an exact match type of query, so I would start with a Composite index. You can cut and paste this to try it out in the Titan Console.

```
graph = TitanFactory.open('inmemory')
mgmt = graph.openManagement()
name = mgmt.makePropertyKey('name').dataType(String.class).cardinality(Cardinality.SINGLE).make()
nameIndex = mgmt.buildIndex('nameIndex',Vertex.class).addKey(name).buildCompositeIndex()
mgmt.commit()
graph.addVertex('name','jason')
g = graph.traversal()
g.V().has('name','jason') // no warning should appear
```

If after reading the [Composite vs Mixed Index](http://s3.thinkaurelius.com/docs/titan/1.0.0/indexes.html#_composite_vs_mixed_index) section you decide that a Mixed index (backed by Elasticsearch, Solr, or Lucene) is what you really need, read Chapter 20 "[Index Parameters and Full-Text Search](http://s3.thinkaurelius.com/docs/titan/1.0.0/index-parameters.html)", and digest the differences between the mappings TEXT, STRING, and TEXTSTRING.

Here's an example that uses a STRING mixed index

```
graph = TitanFactory.build().set('storage.backend','inmemory').set('index.search.backend','elasticsearch').open()
mgmt = graph.openManagement()
name = mgmt.makePropertyKey('name').dataType(String.class).cardinality(Cardinality.SINGLE).make()
nameIndex = mgmt.buildIndex('nameIndex',Vertex.class).addKey(name, Mapping.STRING.asParameter()).buildMixedIndex("search")
mgmt.commit()
graph.addVertex('name','jason')
g = graph.traversal()
g.V().has('name','jason') // no warning should appear
```